# Foreach error when insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got some error when inserting my data. for data 1-20 , the data inserted well. But after that foreach not inserted all data. Here is the data :

```
<?php 
include "../conn.php";
$source="https://source1.com/json";
$file=file_get_contents($source,true);
$char_parse=json_decode($file,true);

foreach($char_parse['data'] as $a_item){
$item_sold=$char_parse2['item_sold'];
$success=$char_parse2['success'];
$reject=$char_parse2['reject'];
$sqli="INSERT INTO `product` VALUES (NULL, '".$item_sold."', '".$success."', '".$reject."')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
$i++;
}
$?>
```

Please help me solve this issues

Comment: Any chance you provide the error message?

Comment: For a start, use prepared statements and PDO.

Comment: @zerkms there is no error mesage. but the data not inserted well. in 80 row, maybe just 76 and sometime 74 data.

Comment: @RadenJohannesHeryoPriambodo your question is titled "Foreach error"

Comment: what is statements that you mean? @DavidFindlay

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know enough about your data structure.  But based on your code, let's assume...

```
$char_parse['data'] = array(
    array('item_sold'=>'item1', 'success'=>1, 'reject'=>2),
    array('item_sold'=>'item2', 'success'=>1, 'reject'=>2)
);
```

Then,

```
foreach($char_parse['data'] as $a_item){
    $item_sold = $a_item['item_sold'];
    $success = $a_item['success'];
    $reject = $a_item['reject'];
    $sqli = "INSERT INTO `product` VALUES (NULL, '".$item_sold."', '".$success."', '".$reject."')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);
}
```

If I'm wrong about the data structure, the proposed code won't work.

Comment: OP really needs to go back and used prepared statements. Any solution should show them.

Comment: OP's code has obvious problems regardless the use of prepared statements.  Prepared statements only repair his problem if the data is compromising the query.  Now, that might be true, but without an example of the data there's no evidence the data is corrupting and no evidence prepared statements will help.  After all, I was actually trying to answer his question, not simply police his coding style.  Which reminds me, where's your solution?  Or are you only interested in policing best practices?

Comment: I'm keen on remind newbies about prepared statements because as previous newbie I didn't learn about them until way, way, way too late.